# Javascript html drop down, selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the selected option of the drop down to the current page it is on. For some reason, unknown to me it's not working.

```
<script>
var temp = '<?php echo $country;?>';
var forma = document.getElementById('forma');
for(var i, j = 0; i = forma.options[j]; j++) {
if(i.value == temp) {
    forma.selectedIndex = j;
    break;
  }
}
</script>

<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="aw">Aruba</option>
<option value="bh">Bahrain</option>
<option value="bj">Benin</option>
<option value="bo">Bolivia</option>
etc..
```

The expected result is, when $country = "aw" it should say; "Aruba".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply set value of `select` input as value of `$country`

Try this:

```js
var temp = 'aw';
$('select[name="forma"]').val(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="forma">
  <option value="aw">Aruba</option>
  <option value="bh">Bahrain</option>
  <option value="bj">Benin</option>
  <option value="bo">Bolivia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Click on __Run the code snippet__ and check. Have you included `jQuey` ?

Comment: Glad to help! __Happy coding__